# Merge and synonymize [flutter-http] and [dart-http]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [flutter-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-http) and [dart-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart-http) tags both appear to generally refer to the use of the same [http dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/http).

I propose that we merge and synonymize the two tags so that [flutter-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-http) points to [dart-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart-http). [flutter-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-http) does have slightly more questions at 55 while [dart-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart-http) only has 40. However, since this package is a dart package that is not specific to flutter, I believe it would be less confusing to make [dart-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart-http) the canonical.

These tags also both have some questions that aren't related to this package and should be cleaned up, but it would probably be best to do following a merge.